# Using Flex Binding instead of addEventListenter

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

I am working with Swiz and in my project I have two domain classes, one of them contains an array of the other class. I want to dispatch an event when one property in that other class change and then call a service from my controller, but since I can't inject the swiz dispatcher in a non-bean class (and would be a bad practice), I want to bind that property to my presentation model and dispatch my event from there. I have it done through event listeners, but I don't know if there is a better way to do it with data binding, like Brian Kotek says here http://groups.google.com/group/swiz-framework/browse_thread/thread/0123076126c9b643

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you make your question more specific.  First, what is a domain class?  You want to dispatch an event when one property of **WHICH** Class changes?  You want to bind **WHAT** property to your presentation model?  You have **WHAT** done through event listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample code would help though but maybe you mean instead of using "addEventListener" you could use the [BindingUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html) that come with the Flex Framework.
You can either bind two properties in different classes (*bindProperty*) or you can bind a method to a property (*bindSetter*). This  method is called every time the value of the property changes.